# Google Maps Intent - avoid highways and tolls? (android)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this but can't find one. Basically I am trying to launch the google maps application to get driving directions somewhere. How do I add the flags for avoiding highways and tolls? 
I've tried appending the following to my url to no avail. 
for highways:

```
&dirflag=h
&avoid=highways
```

It ignores any parameters I pass to the intent. Can I do a putextra to the google maps app?

Here is my url as is:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + mylatitude + "," + 
mylongitude + "&daddr=" + 
anotherlat + "," + anotherlong;
if(somethingischecked) {    
url += AVOID_HIGHWAYS_FLAG?
}                   
Intent toMaps = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the "dirflg" parameter, not "dirflag".

```
dirflg=h, Avoid highways.
dirflg=t, Avoid tolls.
dirflg=r, Public transit but it only works in some areas.
dirflg=w, Walking but still in beta.
dirflg=b, Biking  but only works in some areas and still in beta.
```

for example, if you want to avoid highway:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat_A+ "," + lng_B + "&daddr=" + lat_B + "," + lng_B + "&dirflg=h";
```

And if you want to avoid both highway and tolls:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat_A+ "," + lng_B + "&daddr=" + lat_B + "," + lng_B + "&dirflg=h,t";
```